# Generic class defined with XAML

Tags: c#, class, xaml, generics

There are numerous examples of how to define a class in XAML using a **generic base** type. You'd do something like:

```
<local:A
            x:Class="B"
            x:TypeArguments="local:Foo"
<local:A/>
-----------------
public class B : A<Foo> { }
```

But what if I want to make **class A** generic as well? Something like:

```
<local:A
            x:Class="B"
            x:TypeArguments="T" // Compiler error: "The type "T" was not found"
<local:A/>
-----------------
public class B<T> : A<T> { }
```

Is this simply impossible to do in XAML?

Comment: AFAIK it's not possible

Comment: That's quite a huge let down from XAML, right? Can someone explain why the team behind WPF hasn't been able to do this? Why is this such a big deal?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you don't define classes in XAML, you are simply creating instances of already defined classes, so when you write

```
<local:A
        x:Class="B"
        x:TypeArguments="local:Foo"
<local:A/>
```

you are creating an instance of A passing Foo as the type argument and while instantiating an GenericType you cant pass T.

Think like this when you are creating a new generic list can you write `new List<T>()`

Comment: That's not true. If A weren't generic, I could simply define a new class A, which can then be instantiated anywhere else as actual type A. So I guess it simply won't be possible to have a generic code-behind... :-(